# "Wildcard" key with foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = ["person1" => ["person2" => ["something", "something else", "something else again"], "person3" => ["hey", "hi", "hello"]], "person4" => ["person5" => ["bob", "bill", "bobby", "billy"], "person6" => ["there", "their", "here"]]]
```

or, in other "words"

```
$array = Array(
    "person1" => Array(
        "person2" => Array(
            "something", "something else", "something else again"),
        "person3" => Array(
            "hey", "hi", "hello")
    ),
    "person4" => Array(
        "person5" => Array(
            "bob", "bill", "bobby", "billy"),
        "person6" => Array(
            "there", "their", "here")
    )
);
```

I have a `foreach` loop that looks like this:

```
foreach($array["person1"] as $value){
}
```

I want to get to the third level of the array (where all the words like "something" are), but there's a key in the way that I don't know ("person2" or "person3")
Is there a sort of "wildcard" I can use as the key? (Like `$array["person1"][wildcard][0]`?

Comment: Your array looks a bit strange, why are some persons in other persons while others aren't? Anyway, is the list you want always in the first child element of the first top element in the array?

Comment: The array is basically saying person1 has a request from person2, and then the array with key person2 has information about the request
The output I want from the foreach will always be the 1rd element of the array. So basically with the example array I put up there I want the foreach loop to give me: `something` and `hey`

Comment: Do you want the key as well or just the string "something" and "hey"?

Comment: Just "something" and "hey"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "wildcards" for array keys, since the keys are identifiers.

Simply iterate through the array and echo the first element:

```
foreach ($array['person1'] as $key => $items) {
    // $key will contain the key, if you would need it.
    // $items contains the array of each child
    echo $items[0] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Jeez, I'm dumb... Thanks

Comment: No problem. It's easy to get stuck on silly things sometimes. :)